# How to reduce number of if's in custom deserializer

Tags: java, jackson, sonarlint

I analyzed my custom JSON deserializer with SonarLint and it says that I should reduce Cognitive Complexitiy from 21 to at least 15. In other words it means that I have to much of if statements. My deserializer looks like this:

```
   @Override
    public Movie deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(p);

        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setId(node.get("id").textValue());
        movie.setTitle(node.get("movieInfo").get("title").textValue());

        int identifiersSize = node.get("movieInfo").get("identifiers").size();
        String IMSC="";
        for(int i=0;i<identifiersSize;i++){
            if(node.get("movieInfo").get("identifiers").get(i).get("type").textValue().equals("IMSC")){
                IMSC = node.get("movieInfo").get("identifiers").get(i).get("identifier").textValue();
            }
        }
        if(IMSC.isEmpty()){
            IMSC = node.get("id").textValue();
        }
        movie.setIMSC(IMSC);

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("subtitle")){
            movie.setSubtitle(node.get("movieInfo").get("subtitle").textValue());
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("publishedDate")){
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            LocalDate date;
            try {
                date = LocalDate.parse(node.get("movieInfo").get("publishedDate").asText(), formatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e){
                date = LocalDate.of(node.get("movieInfo").get("publishedDate").asInt(),1,1);
            }
            movie.setPublishedDate(date);
        }


        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("publisher")){
            movie.setPublisher(node.get("movieInfo").get("publisher").textValue());
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("description")){
            movie.setDescription(node.get("movieInfo").get("description").textValue());
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("length")){
            movie.setLength(node.get("movieInfo").get("length").asInt());
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("imageLinks")){
            movie.setThumbnailUrl(node.get("movieInfo").get("imageLinks").get("thumbnail").asText());
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("language")){
            movie.setLanguage(node.get("movieInfo").get("language").asText());
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("previewLink")){
            movie.setPreviewLink(node.get("movieInfo").get("previewLink").asText());
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("ratingsCount")) {
            movie.setRatingsCount(node.get("movieInfo").get("ratingsCount").asInt());
            movie.setAverageRating(node.get("movieInfo").get("averageRating").doubleValue());
        }


        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("authors")) {
            List<String> authors= new ArrayList<>();
            int size = node.get("movieInfo").get("authors").size();
            for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
               authors.add(node.get("movieInfo").get("authors").get(i).asText());
            }
            movie.setAuthors(authors);
        }

        if(node.get("movieInfo").has("categories")) {
            List<String> categories= new ArrayList<>();
            int size = node.get("movieInfo").get("categories").size();
            for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
            categories.add(node.get("movieInfo").get("categories").get(i).asText());
            }
            movie.setCategories(categories);
        }

        return movie;
    }
```

My questions is: is there any better way of doing that? I would like to have zero errors from SonarLint.

Comment: Can you show 2 or 3 more ifs so that we can see the similarities and differences between them?

Comment: Also what is the `movie` object?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I updated my question with code of deserialization function

Comment: In theory you could invoke setter via reflection. That way you will get one `if` for all of them in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be calling `node.get("movieInfo")` and `node.get("id")` a lot of times.  You could simplify the code substantially by caching the values of those two calls in local variables.

But I don't think there is a **good** way to substantially reduce the `if` statements.  (You might be able recude the `if` statements by creating a table of lambdas and then iterating the "keys" of your node, looking up and calling the corresponding lambda.  But I doubt that would make the code easier to read.)

You could possibly split the method into sub-methods and reduce the number of `if` statements per method.  That will probably make SonarLint happier, but it is debatable that it make the code more readable.

---

> I would like to have zero errors from SonarLint.

That's not what your goal should be.  The ostensible purpose of tools like SonarLint is to help you make your code more readable and maintainable by means of artificial measures of code code complexity.  However:

- Programmers can generally deal with the kind of complexity shown here.  This code is more repetitive than complex.
- Sometimes the complexity is inherent in the task you are trying to perform.